# What does it mean to "simultaneously localize a function in time and frequency domain"?

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

What does the statement "simultaneously localize a function in time and frequency domain" mean when it comes to signals and systems? What does it mean to localize?

Comment: You might want to check out the [variance formulation of the uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Wave_mechanics_interpretation).

Answer (score 3):

The Fourier transform of a nonzero function with compact support does not have compact support. So if something is "local in time" (i.e. it vanishes outside a finite time interval), then it is not "local in frequency" (i.e. it does not vanish outside any finite frequency interval). Similarly, the inverse Fourier transform of a nonzero function with compact support does not have compact support. So if something is "local in frequency" (i.e. it vanishes outside a finite frequency interval) then it is not "local in time" (i.e. it does not vanish outside any finite time interval).

The above is a qualitative manifestation of this "uncertainty principle". A quantitative version can be stated as follows. Take $f$ such that $\| f \|_{L^2}=1$. Let $\xi$ be a random variable with PDF $|f(x-a)|^2$ and $\eta$ be a random variable with PDF $|\hat{f}(x-b)|^2$. (Here I have used the Plancherel theorem to note that $\| \hat{f} \|_{L^2}=1$.) Then the variance of $\xi$ is at least a constant divided by the variance of $\eta$, and vice versa. Thus the two variances cannot simultaneously tend to zero. So if the "mass" of $f$ is concentrated near some number $a$, then the "mass" of $\hat{f}$ cannot be concentrated near any number $b$, and vice versa.

A helpful document on the subject: http://www2.math.umd.edu/~begue/Expository/Uncertainty.pdf

Comment: what is "compact support"?

Comment: @quantum231 The support of a function is the closure of the set of points where the function is nonzero. For example, if $f(x)=\max \{ 1-|x|,0 \}$, then the support of $f$ is $[-1,1]$. In this setting, a set is compact if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: @quantum231, [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactSupport.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactSupport.html) ... _I think_ in grossly oversimplified terms, a function with "compact support" tends to zero outside a particular neighborhood, i.e. it's localized?

Comment: @jrodatus A function does not merely tend to zero outside of its support; a function must exactly take the value of zero at points outside of its support.